# Display a dialog in portrait mode in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-orientation

I have my activity in landscape mode(declared in manifest file). Now in that activity, if any dialog appears, it is shown in landscape mode.

Is there any way of showing dialog orientation according to device's orientation even if my activity is in landscape mode?

Comment: By that you mean reducing the dialog width or do you mean rotating the dialog? :p

Comment: I don't want to reduce dialog width/height. My dialog width/height is enough to display properly in both mode. I just want it to show according to system's orienation.

Comment: So you mean rotating the dialog. The activity from where it pops up is locked to landscape, and it spawns a dialog that you want to rotate automatically. However, I wouldn't do it since the activity behind should still be locked to landscape, not making much sense to see the dialog in portrait with the activity behind behaving differently, as I said. I don't think you can even do that without customizing classes and doing some lower level stuff (if even possible at all). If the new dialog behaves so differently, I'd create a new activity with the actions you want for it.